# Is there any reason why assigning a value to evt.target would cause an error in only Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, mobile-safari

I have a really weird issue where the following line of code is causing an error in only Mobile Safari:

```
evt.target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
```

Basically, I have an `onclick` event set up for a div that has a bunch of `a` elements within it. When an `a` element within the div is clicked on, I want to figure out which `a` element was clicked on. I'm using the following code for this purpose:

```
document.getElementById('the_div').onclick = someFunc(callbackFunction);    
function someFunc(callbackFunction) {      
  return function (evt) {        
    evt = evt || window.event;        
    evt.target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;        
    // More code here in which callbackFunction is used with evt.target.        
    return false;        
  };      
}
```

What is confusing though is that the code works perfectly fine in every browser I've tested it in except Mobile Safari. It works fine in all the following browsers:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera
- IE6-10
- Safari (on Windows)

However, on Mobile Safari, the `evt.target` assignment causes an error, and then causes the URL in the `href` attribute of the `a` element to be followed. (I'd like to be able to view the error being caused, but I'm not sure how to do that in Mobile Safari.)

If I change the code above to the following, then everything works fine (notice the `target` variable declaration):

```
document.getElementById('the_div').onclick = someFunc(callbackFunction);    
function someFunc(callbackFunction) {      
  return function (evt) {        
    evt = evt || window.event;        
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;        
    // More code here in which callbackFunction is used with target.        
    return false;        
  };      
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the `evt.target` assignment would cause issues in only Mobile Safari?

Comment: What if you try `evt.currentTarget` ?

Comment: Well, `evt.currentTarget` is going to point to the div element that's the parent of the `a` elements. That doesn't seem to really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`event.target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-target) is actually supposed to be readonly.

> `target` **of type** [`EventTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-EventTarget), **readonly**

Seems the difference is just whether an `Error` is thrown when you try to set its value. Some engines seem to just ignore it / silently fail.

```
console.log(evt.target); // logs: <div id="the_div" ...></div>

evt.target = {};         // you'd expect it to be a plain `Object`

console.log(evt.target); // but, still logs: <div id="the_div" ...></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YaCv2/

Comment: Wild! So it is! Why would that only seem to be enforced in Mobile Safari? What's more, I set up a simple script on the side with a few `a` elements within a div, and then did the `evt.target = evt.target || evt.srcElement` assignment in that script, and it worked fine without any errors, even in Mobile Safari. I'm starting to wonder if there's something else that's wrong with my script since the simple script worked fine.

Comment: @HartleySan Actually, I think the difference is just whether they `throw` an Exception or silently fail / ignore it. See my edit.

Comment: Okay. That answer works for me. I guess the solution is to just assign the result of `evt.target || evt.srcElement` to a whole new variable from now on. Thanks a lot for researching that for me.